# Pytorch tensor **2computing

Tags: python, pytorch

```
for i in range(180000):
    p[indices[0][i], :, indices[1][i], indices[2][i]] = \
        p[indices[0][i], :, indices[1][i], indices[2][i]] ** 2
```

It needs to comsume 60+ seconds, and `p = p ** 2` can attain the result right now. I just want part of ***P*** to change. So, what should I do to achive this efficiency? Coding by **Pytorch**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I already have known the reasons of it. I should convert indices to cuda format.